# KMeans vs. KMeansClustering in tensorflow.contrib

Tags: python, tensorflow, k-means

According to the documentation of tensorflow there are two classes that relate to Kmeans algorithm. One of them is 
[tensorflow.contrib.factorization.KMeans](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/factorization/KMeans)
 and the other one is [tensorflow.contrib.factorization.KMeansClustering](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/factorization/KMeansClustering).
The documentation states that former is for creating the graph for kmeans clustering but I don't actually get it.
I want to use kmeans for MNIST dataset to cluster digits then classify them. Which class should I use for my code?

Answer (score 1):

I am using sklearn for these kind of jobs but going through the documentation this is what i understand :

KmeansClustering as presented in the example you attach, returns the results of the model in text form : `print 'point:', point, 'is in cluster', cluster_index, 'centered at', center`.

Kmeans does the exact same thing but produces both the model's stats and a graph.

I suggest you try them both and see the differences for your self.